# SQL - Combining 2 queries into a Uncorrelated Query using the Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine two queries into one query using the WHERE clause, as demonstrated in my lesson. The two separate queries work, but when I combine them I get an error. I have tried several different approaches, but the one I feel is closest to what I need is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    Product.product_name, Sizes.Size_option
FROM 
    Product
JOIN 
    Available_in ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
JOIN 
    Sizes ON Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
WHERE 
    Product.product_id IN (SELECT Product.product_id, product.product_name
                           FROM Product
                           JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
                           GROUP BY product.product_id, product.product_name
                           HAVING COUNT(sells.store_location_id) = 5);
```

Comment: Could you tell us what the error is? What your data looks like and what's the desired output? What are you trying to accomplish with the query? You just said you're trying to "combine" two queries with no additional info

Comment: You should ask another question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the subquery is selecting two columns, but you only need one for the `IN`.

Second, you don't even need the `JOIN` in that subquery.

I also think table aliases would help your query writing:

```
SELECT p.product_name, s.Size_option
FROM Product p JOIN
     Available_in a
     ON p.product_id = a.product_id JOIN
     Sizes s
     ON a.sizes_id = s.sizes_id
WHERE p.product_id IN (SELECT s.product_id
                       FROM Sells s
                       GROUP BY s.product_id
                       HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
                      );
```

Alternatively, you could use a correlated subquery for the `WHERE`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Sells s
              WHERE s.product_id = p.product_id
              GROUP BY s.product_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
             )
```

The advantage of writing it this way is that the optimizer can take advantage of an index on `Sells(product_id)` and avoid a `GROUP BY` on the entire `Sells` table.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be what I was looking for. I dissected the first one you gave and reworked it a little to better understand it, then ran it and it worked like a charm.

Follow up question, if I wanted to make the "Having Count" dynamic instead of hardcoding the 5, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Sleepy_Hollows_4 . . . I don't know what you mean by making it "dynamic".  You can pass it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a value so you should select a value only

```
SELECT Product.product_name, Sizes.Size_option
FROM Product
JOIN Available_in ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
JOIN Sizes ON  Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id

       WHERE Product.product_id IN
           (SELECT Product.product_id
            FROM Product
            JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
            GROUP BY product.product_id
            HAVING COUNT(sells.store_location_id) = 5);
```

And you could also use a join instead of `where in (  subselect )`

```
SELECT Product.product_name, Sizes.Size_option
FROM Product
JOIN Available_in ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
JOIN Sizes ON  Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
JOIN   (
    SELECT Product.product_id
    FROM Product
    JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
    GROUP BY product.product_id
    HAVING COUNT(sells.store_location_id) = 5
) T on Product.product_id T.product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of what you are up to, but to use the 'IN' statement just a row of data is supposed to be used as the parameters

```
SELECT Product.product_id, product.product_name
                FROM Product
                JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
                GROUP BY product.product_id, product.product_name
                HAVING COUNT(sells.store_location_id) = 5
```

I don't think this query above is valid, you would need to correct it.

Ensure it returns just one row of data like

```
SELECT Product.product_id
                FROM Product
                JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
                where sells.store_location_id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I might think of another solution that could be much easier. 
You could just do something like this :

```
SELECT 
    product_name, 
    Size_option
FROM (
SELECT
    Product.product_id,
    Product.product_name, 
    Sizes.Size_option, 
    COUNT(sells.store_location_id) OVER(PARTITION BY sells.store_location_id ORDER BY sells.store_location_id) AS SellsQty
FROM Product
JOIN Available_in ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
JOIN Sizes ON Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
) D 
WHERE 
    SellsQty = 5
```